# Python subprocess.check_call works in a different way than bash

Tags: python, r, bash, subprocess

I'm trying to run Rscript via Python using subprocess.check_call.

Rscript is very simple it just checks if Rpackage exists, and if not it installs it.

```
local({r <- getOption("repos")
     r["CRAN"] <- "https://cloud.r-project.org/"
     options(repos=r)
})

if (!require("glue")) install.packages("glue")
```

When I run such command in bash

```sh
Rscript packages.R
```

it works fine.

But when I tried to run it using subprocess.check_call

```py
subprocess.check_call(f"Rscript packages.R",
                      shell=True,
                      env=self.env)
```

I got such error:

```
* installing *source* package 'glue' ...
** package 'glue' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-3.3.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c glue.c -o glue.o
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:132: recipe for target 'glue.o' failed
make: *** [glue.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'glue'
* removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/glue'

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/Rtmpym9Dy9/downloaded_packages'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You evidently took away (the useful value for) `PATH` by providing your own environment.  If you want to be like the shell, make only the minimum necessary changes to the environment you inherit.